# Select element with width: fit-content doesn't get enough width and the text ends up over the dropdown arrow icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Long story short, I'm using react-bootstrap v2 and Bootstrap v5 and I'm giving my `Select` element `width: fit-content` like this:

```
    <Form.Select
        value={value}
        onChange={(ev: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
            onSelect(ev.target.value);
        }}
    >
```

But for whatever reason, the selected option goes over the dropdown icon and I don't understand why considering I'm using `width: fit-content`. Before my upgrade from react-bootstrap v1 and Bootstrap v4 the text was looking good.

I know the text is bigger and bolder, but shouldn't that be handled by `width: 'fit-content'`?

```html
<select class="form-select" style="width: fit-content;padding-right: 20px;"></select>
```

Comment: I would imagine the dropdown is not being accounted for with `width: fit-content;`, you should post your rendered HTML and CSS so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: @カメロン I added the rendered elements and its CSS rules.

Comment: Getting closer ~ edit the snippet until you can see the issue.